# Show a progress bar on a child tab until the WebView loads

Tags: android, webview, progress-bar, android-tabhost

In an Android app I am using a TabView and one of the tabs shows a WebView. But the page is blank until the web page loads. How would one show a progress bar until the page loads? It cannot be in the title bar because that is hidden by the tab host.

Answer (score 17):

I use a ProgressBar for this. With a layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout [...]>

  <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/WebView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

  <ProgressBar 
       android:id="@+id/ProgressBar"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
       android:visibility="gone"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I hide and show the progress indicator using:

```
 WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);

 final ProgressBar progess = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar);

  webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
    progess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }

  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    progess.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a really good tutorial on the [Android Developers website](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog) for that. It shows how to create the 'spinning wheel' progress dialog used throughout Android programs, and even some basics on how to handle loading in a separate thread to prevent your application from freezing while loading.

Comment: In terms of page loading, you can attach a `WebViewClient` to the `WebView` and find out when the page is loaded, so you know when you can dismiss the dialog.

Comment: ok but how to relaunch the progressDialog when clicking on a link inside webview ?

Answer (score 2):

If your question is "how do I find out when the page is loaded?", then:

Create a custom subclass of WebViewClient, overriding onPageFinished()

Attach an instance of your WebViewClient subclass to your WebView via setWebViewClient()

Set up the indefinite progress indicator (bar, dialog, RotateAnimation, etc.)

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", getText(R.string.progressDialogText), true);
```

before calling loadUrl() on the WebView

Have onPageFinished() get rid of the progress indicator (progressDialog.dismiss())