# how to show progress bar on webview?

Tags: android

I am trying to open a webpage in my application using `WebView`. When I open webpage it shows me blank screen for a while and then open that page in browser inside my application.

Anyone suggest me how to show progress or get rid of that blank screen which comes during loading of webview?

I am using following code:

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mywebview);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

// error handling
final Activity activity = this;

mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

// error  handling

mWebView.loadUrl(URL);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android WebView progress bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537454/android-webview-progress-bar)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try this:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mywebview);

mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

final Activity activity = this;

mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

         public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                 activity.setTitle("Loading...");
                 activity.setProgress(progress * 100);
                    if(progress == 100)
                       activity.setTitle("My title");
                 }
});

mWebView.loadUrl(URL);
```

Comment: when I click url open via chrome application. But I want to open it on my web view with line progressbar.

Comment: Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS is deprecated

Comment: Activity's setProgress() is deprecated as well.

Comment: activity.setProgress(progress ONLY. NOT * 100);

Answer (score 23):

Here is the code that I am using:

Inside WebViewClient:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        findViewById(R.id.progress1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        findViewById(R.id.progress1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

});
```

Here is the XML :

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 11):

You need to do something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    this.setProgressBarVisibility(true);
}
```

And then

```
final Activity activity = this;
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
        activity.setProgress(progress * 100);
    }
});
```

**Update**
I know it is a bit too late but I have little side note: you shouldn't use `setWebViewClient()` twice. Second call cancels the first call so you wouldn't get error handling.

Answer (score 3):

*1.  In oncreate ur **call AsyncTask**.*

*2.  In asynctask u just make progress dialog and show progress dialog.*

*3.  In webview client u just show again progress dialog click  on any link of web site which open in ur webview and after complete load link we **override method**  **onPageFinished** and in this method we dismiss the progress dialog.*

**oncreate**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.web_view);

    web_view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);

    OpenWebSiteInWebView opensite = new OpenWebSiteInWebView();
    opensite.execute();

}
```

**AsyncTask**

```
private class OpenWebSiteInWebView extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        web_view.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        web_view.loadUrl("ur site name");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        pd = new ProgressDialog(SiteOpenInWebView.this);
        pd.setMessage("Please wait Loading...");
        pd.show();

    }

}
```

**WebViewClient**

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);

        if (!pd.isShowing()) {
            pd.show();
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        System.out.println("on finish");
        if (pd.isShowing()) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I'm using in **KOTLIN**:

```
private fun setupWebView() {

    val webViewClient: WebViewClient = object: WebViewClient() {

        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {
            view?.loadUrl(request?.url.toString())
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request)
        }

        override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
            showProgressDialog()
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
        }

        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
            hideProgressDialog()
            super.onPageFinished(view, url)
        }
    }
    webView.webViewClient = webViewClient

    webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webView.settings.defaultTextEncodingName = "utf-8"
}
```