# How to show a progress bar for a layout until the WebView is loaded

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-webview

I am loading a WebView to the LinearLayout and want to display a ProgressBar inside this layout until the WebView is fully loaded.I wnet through the below links and they seems to be really great but I do not want to use **ProgressDialog**, instead I would like to use progressbar inside the layout.

http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/07/31/load-webview-with-progressdialog/

[how to show progress bar on webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903895/how-to-show-progress-bar-on-webview)

How would I do that?

Say for example,

```
if(pos==0)
{
 mLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 mWeb.loadUrl("http://android.stackexchange.com/");
}
```

Inside `mLayout` I would like to display a progressbar until the page gets displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the webView setPictureListener() like this:

```
// here you can start a loading wheel

   webView.setPictureListener(new WebView.PictureListener() {
      public void onNewPicture(WebView webView, Picture picture) {
           // close your loading wheel here
            }
        });

   //load your url
   webView.loadUrl(yourUrl);
```

Comment: +1. Although PictureListener is deprecated, I bet there's no other way to do this correctly (at least not yet).

Answer (score 7):

To define progress bar inside webview:

**1.** Define `ProgressBar` and `Webview` inside your layout like this:

```
<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="8px"
        android:max="100"
        android:visibility="gone" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fadingEdge="none" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webkit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</ScrollView>
```

**2.** Inside your activity:

```
    progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

    progressBar.setProgress(0);

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    WebView mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webkit);

    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

         progressBar.setProgress(progress);
         if(progress == 100) {
             progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          }
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this is a better way ti detect that a page loading is finished.

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```