# Android: Progress Bar is not dismissing even though Page loading is finished

Tags: android

Progress Bar is not dismissing even though Page loading is finished
I'm trying to load the url in the webview in background so that user doesn't able to recognize that it is some other website that opens.. I want them to think that the whatever is opening in the webview is the part of the application itself. Therefore I'm trying to open url in background and till the time url loads I want progress bar to appear but as page loaded I'm dismissing progress bar but it continues to appear.. it is not dismissing, thats the problem.. please help me out

Here is my code...

```
package com.example.urlopeningwithprogressbar;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ProgressDialog pg;
Background bg;
WebView wv;
Button b1;

static boolean buttonpressed=false;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            bg = new Background();
            bg.execute();


        }
    });


}
public void progress(){
    pg = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    pg.setTitle("");
    pg.setMessage("Please Wait.........");
    pg.setCancelable(false);
    pg.setIndeterminate(true);
    pg.show();
}

class Background extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            try{
                wv.loadUrl("URL");
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
                wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
                wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            //  wv.setWebViewClient(new ourViewClient());



        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Process Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pre execute is working??", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        progress();
    }
}
 public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            pg.dismiss();
        }
    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: is onPageFinished called?

Comment: Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903895/how-to-show-progress-bar-on-webview

Comment: @Ascorbin onPageFinished Doesn't called...

Comment: @Ameeshmg I followed the same which is given in the link u gave.. But still facing the problem.. Can anyone point out where is the flaw in the code..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never instantiating or using your `myWebClient` class. 
You have to

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
```

to actually use it. 
Also note that class names should be upper case.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy :) Its working now :) I wish I could vote up for u but as I joined stackoverflow just a day before so doesn't have reputation above 15 so can't voteup for u