# WebView.getProgress() always returning 100

Tags: android, progress-bar, webview

I am experiencing the same bug reported here (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9597)

Anyone know of a work around?  I want to have a progress bar in a WebView like the Android Browser does while the page is loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement a `WebChromeClient` to capture the progress change with the `onProgressChanged()` method:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onProgressChanged(android.webkit.WebView, int)

See the answer to this question: [Android WebView progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537454/android-webview-progress-bar)

And you can actually see an example in the WebView documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html