# Add a Progress Bar in WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, progressdialog, android-progressbar

I am trying to add a progress/loading bar to my application that uses `WebView`. I am confused on how to implement a progress bar that appears every time a link is clicked.

Current code:

```
public class CULearnBrowser extends Activity {

    WebView webview;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl("https://culearn.colorado.edu/webct/entryPageIns.dowebct");
    }

    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webview.canGoBack()) {
            webview.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/hello" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The answer you are looking for is highly detailed in here: http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=1331

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android WebView progress bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537454/android-webview-progress-bar)

Comment: How to download a pdf or doc on Button click from WebView

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I have added few lines in your code and now its working fine with progress bar.

```
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.main );
        // Makes Progress bar Visible
        getWindow().setFeatureInt( Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);

        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)   
            {
                //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded, and changes string to Loading...
                setTitle("Loading...");
                setProgress(progress * 100); //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded
     
                // Return the app name after finish loading
                if(progress == 100)
                   setTitle(R.string.app_name);
                }
            });
        webview.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: ive seen stuff like that but i dont know how to do it with my code

Comment: Without seeing your whole code, It is not possible to understand.

Comment: ive attached the xml this is the only other file

Comment: the progress bar should only be implemented in the java code i feel like

Comment: It is working on my system. I can give you the whole sample code.

Comment: Is it possible to display a spinner in the center of the webview instead of the progress bar while the URL is loading?

Comment: final Activity activity = this;

final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setProgress(0);
        activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);

        progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(progress);

        if(progress == 100 && progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
});

Comment: @Sandy +1 Great answer. Both solutions are working like a charm. I would suggest adding your last comment as an alternative to your solution.

Comment: why do you have chrome client & even web client registered ?

Comment: is it compulsory to use WebChromeClient?Can i use Webclient instead of WebChromeClient???

Comment: `setProgress()` is deprecated starting with API 21. What to do?

Comment: @soshial: You can create custom progress bar and show/hide as per usage.

Comment: @PratikButaniAndroidDev: You can use code sample which I had pasted here. Link may be down.

Comment: @Sandy `new HelloWebViewClient()` also missing. Its tough to understand for newbie. please post it and remove invalid redirection.

Answer (score 20):

pass your url in this method

```
private void startWebView(String url) {

        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();

        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ContestActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.show();

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(ContestActivity.this, "Error:" + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }
```

Answer (score 16):

in **oncreate** method where you have set your Webview.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.web_view);

web_view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
pd = new ProgressDialog(SiteOpenInWebView.this);
    pd.setMessage("Please wait Loading...");
    pd.show();
    web_view.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    web_view.loadUrl("ur site name");
 }
```

**WebViewClient**

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);

    if (!pd.isShowing()) {
        pd.show();
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    System.out.println("on finish");
    if (pd.isShowing()) {
        pd.dismiss();
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried so many codes but no code working on the webview of the progressbar.but this code is working fine thanks Nitesh Khosla

Comment: same as it is your code no change progressbar instead of progressdialog

Answer (score 9):

Here is the code that I am using:

Inside WebViewClient:

```
               @Override
             public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

              super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
              findViewById(R.id.progress1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                findViewById(R.id.progress1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
```

Here is the XML :

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 8):

The best approch which worked for me is

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
          super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
          mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
          webView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

    @Override public void onPageCommitVisible(WebView view, String url) {
      super.onPageCommitVisible(view, url);
      mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
      webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      isWebViewLoadingFirstPage=false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this boolean isWebViewLoadingFirstPage, where to initialize this ?

Comment: onPageStarted is very late - the progress spinner doesn't show for most of the time I want it to. shouldOverrideUrlLoading (see answer above https://stackoverflow.com/a/57068625/826946) works better for me

Answer (score 7):

Put a progress bar and the webview inside a relativelayout and set the properties for the progress bar as follows,

1. Make its visibility as GONE.
2. CENTRE it in the Relativelayout.

and then in onPageStarted() of the webclient make the progress bar visible so that it shows the progressbar when you have clicked on a link. In onPageFinished()  make the progress bar visiblility as GONE so that it disappears when the page has finished loading... This will work fine for your scenario. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 2):

I try dismis progress on method **onPageFinished()**, but not good too much, it has time delay to render webview.

try with **onPageCommitVisible() better:**

```
val progressBar = ProgressDialog(context)
    progressBar.setCancelable(false)
    progressBar.show()
    val url = "your url here"
    web_container.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    web_container.loadUrl(url)

    web_container.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
            view.loadUrl(url)
            progressBar.show()
            return true
        }

        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url)
        }
        override fun onPageCommitVisible(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
            super.onPageCommitVisible(view, url)
            progressBar.dismiss()
        }
    }
    web_container.setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener { _, keyCode, event ->
        if (keyCode == KEYCODE_BACK && event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                && web_container.canGoBack()) {
            web_container.goBack()
            return@OnKeyListener true
        }
        return@OnKeyListener false
    })
```