# Display Progress Bar until the response comes from server

Tags: android

I want to display some text from server, but till then I want to display Progress Bar.
Can anyone help me out. Response is in the form of `JSON`

Comment: Use doInBackground of AsyncTask to request to the server.show progrss dialog on onPreExecute and in onPostExecute cancel dialog and handle response

Comment: In which form do you get the response?XML or JASON or just a html page? if html then you can go with xDragonZ. Be specific about your question plz.

Comment: Wow response in form of JASON not M.MEYERS?  You mean JSON right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used AsyncTask to do this before.  Make the progress dialog display in onPreExecute, and dismiss it in onPostExecute.  Works very nicely, and it's nice and clean.

http://javatech.org/2011/02/discovering-android-opening-a-progress-dialog-with-asynctask/

Answer (score 4):

how about this?

[Add a Progress Bar in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331094/how-to-add-a-progress-bar-in-webview)

http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/08/04/adding-progress-bar-on-webview-android-tutorials/

```
final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Please Wait",
            true);


    final WebView engine = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    engine.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            if (pd.isShowing() && pd != null) {
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    engine.loadUrl("http://www.domain.com/");
```