# how to set progress bar on activity

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, android-activity

This is my code...

```
public class detailedview extends Activity
{
    WebView mWebView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detailedview);
        GetSet gs = new GetSet();

        String title = gs.getTitle();
        String desc = gs.getDesc();

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setTextSize(TextSize.SMALLER);
        mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", "<p  align=\"justify\"><b> " + title+"</p></b><p align=\"justify\"><br>"+ desc + "</p></br>", "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

I want to set a `ProgressBar` on the `Activity`. How can I achieve this?
help me.

Comment: please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331094/how-to-add-a-progress-bar-in-webview and override the function public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) of Webivew http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/08/04/adding-progress-bar-on-webview-android-tutorials/

Answer (score 1):

The below code is used to show the progress bar:

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please Wait!", "Loading...");
```

and to disable it:

```
if (progressDialog != null) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

UPDATE:

```
this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS,
                Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
        final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        final Activity MyActivity = this;
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                // Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded, and changes
                // string to Loading...
                MyActivity.setTitle("Loading...");
                MyActivity.setProgress(progress * 100); // Make the bar
                                                        // disappear after URL
                                                        // is loaded

                // Return the app name after finish loading
                if (progress == 100)
                    MyActivity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }
        });
```

Comment: loadDataWithBaseURL how i will put this function what argument i ll put here when  i will put webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
             public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
               
                 view.loadUrl(url);
                 return true;
             }

Comment: view.loadUrl(url); this i will have to apply  in shouldOverrideUrlLoading() functaion right but in our code

Comment: in load() , this loadDataWithBaseURL() funcation is there which has argumnet when i appy this then they ask for 5 argument wat we have to fill in that argumnt????