# how to add progress bar in tab2 webView

Tags: android, webview

i want to add a progress in a webView but when i tried to add progress bar by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331094/how-to-add-a-progress-bar-in-webview) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537454/android-webview-progress-bar) but it's so confusing i can't undersatnd i am a newbie.

i want to add a progress bar in my tab2 activity

```
package com.freerechargeapp.weebly.free_recharge_app;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class tab2 extends Fragment {



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);





    WebView webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview1);
    webView.loadUrl("http://google.com");



    return view;



}
```

}

here is my tab2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"


 />

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"/>




</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: http://javatechig.com/android/progressbar-while-loading-webview

Comment: Please follow above URL

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya It's too much confusing i am a newbie i can't understand that.

Comment: post your `tab2` xml

Comment: http://www.technotalkative.com/android-load-webview-with-progressbar/

Comment: hello @IntelliJAmiya i have updated tab2.xml

Comment: Did you check above url ?? where is progressbar

Comment: yeah i added progressbar in my tab2.xml, now what? @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: Check my below answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way,

```
public class tab2 extends Fragment {

WebView webView ;
 ProgressBar progressBar;

  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);



        webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview1);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://google.com");

        return view;
  }

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: i added your code it saying cannot resolve findViewById(int) here is the screenshot of it [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/Ud5FRkC.png) @IntelliJ

Comment: `progressBar = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);`

Comment: @Stevenjobs Check my above comment

Comment: @Stevenjobs Waiting for your feedback

Comment: Hello @IntelliJ it's not working when the first page load (google.com) after then it's working fine here's is a [video](https://youtu.be/zZAq9NZoFxw) of that.

Comment: @Stevenjobs Your first tab is a fragment please add this code there . This code works fine in here

Comment: what do you mean i don't get you, where should i add this code in tab1.java tab2.java or MainActivity.java @IntelliJ

Comment: Are you newbie probably .Okay.Similarly you can add this tab1 fragment