# Pass the url to WebView

Tags: android, webview, barcode-scanner

I am trying to pass the URL to the [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) that I got from the QR code but I have no idea how to do this, I tried putExtras in the intent but when I scan the QR code and press the visit button the app goes back to the main_activity.

**How can I pass the URL, I am getting from QR code to WebView**

here in this code, I am appending the URL...
the QR code contains /images text...
when I am appending the URL it becomes http://google.com/images...i want to pass this URL to the WebView

**And I also want to show progressbar when the url is loading how can i do the same??**

**Scan.java**

```
public class Scan extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;
    private ZXingScannerView scannerView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        setContentView(scannerView);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            if(checkPermission()){
                Toast.makeText(Scan.this,"Permission is granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                requestPermission();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkPermission(){
        return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Scan.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    }
    private void requestPermission(){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        scannerView.stopCamera();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            if(checkPermission()){
                if(scannerView == null){
                    scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
                    setContentView(scannerView);
                }
                scannerView.setResultHandler(this);
                scannerView.startCamera();   
            }else {
                requestPermission();
            }
        }    
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {
        final String scanResult = "http://google.com" + result.getText();

        Web web = new Web(scanResult);

        //final String appendResult = "http://google.com" + scanResult;

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
        /* builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
               // scannerView.resumeCameraPreview(Scan.this);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                finish();
            }
        });*/
        builder.setPositiveButton("Visit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Scan.this, WebResult.class);
                intent.putExtra("title",scanResult);
                startActivity(intent);

                // Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(scanResult));
               // startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        builder.setMessage(scanResult);
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }

}
```

**web_result.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="example.android.com.qrscannertest.WebResult">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></WebView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**WebResult.java**

```
public class WebResult extends AppCompatActivity {

    Web web;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_result);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String url = null;

        if(extras != null){
            url = extras.getString("url");
        }

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished( WebView view, String url ) {

                super.onPageFinished(webView, url );

                //Make Enable or Disable buttons
              //  backbtn.setEnabled(view.canGoBack());
                //fwdbtn.setEnabled(view.canGoForward());

            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError( WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl ) {

                super.onReceivedError( webView, errorCode, description, failingUrl );
                Toast.makeText( WebResult.this, description, Toast.LENGTH_LONG );
            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl(url);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do **`setContentView()`** first than perform  **`findViewById`**

Use this

```
WebView webView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_result);
      webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
```

Instead of this

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_result);
```

**EDIT**

Also use same key while pass data using intent like this

Use this

```
 url = extras.getString("title");
```

instead of this

```
 url = extras.getString("url");
```

To show **`ProgressBar`** with webview check this ans [**How to add a progress/loading bar in WebView**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47885692/7666442)

Answer (score 0):

You put Key `title` and getting key `url` , How is this gonna work anyway .

```
String url = null;
    if(extras != null){
        url = extras.getString("title");
    }
```

Also call `setContentView()` first then find the views .

Comment: how can i show the progressbar ?

Comment: @HarshSharma check this ans it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/47885692/7666442