# Unable to dismiss Progress dialog after loading a page in Webview

Tags: android, webview, progressdialog

Can anyone help me when I add this `ProgressDialog` to my `Webview` app its work fine but when the page is loaded the `progress dialog` is not dismissed can anyone help me I am using this code in `Fragment`

```
public static ProgressDialog progressDialog;

     mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                    progressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Loading...", "Please wait YouTube is Loading...");

                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

                }


                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    getActivity().setTitle(view.getTitle());
                    if(progressDialog!=null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                }
            });
```

Edited code which is working for me now thanks to everyone who help me

```
public static ProgressDialog progressDialog;

//Under onCreate View
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Loading...", "Please wait YouTube is Loading...");

mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

            }


            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                getActivity().setTitle(view.getTitle());
                if(progressDialog!=null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    progressDialog.hide();
                }
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a progress/loading bar in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47885592/how-to-add-a-progress-loading-bar-in-webview)

Comment: @Suman Dey can you post ur full code??

Comment: @Jeeva sorry I can not post the full line of code because the code is about 1000 line and have some serious codes which I can not share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that  `if(progressDialog!=null && progressDialog.isShowing())` this condition returns true. Put a break point there and make sure they both are true.

try

```
 progressDialog.hide()
```

Comment: How to do that can you explain with more details and codes??

Comment: Thanks for your help its work I use this code and its work fine

Answer (score 0):

Move below line out of `onPageStarted()` method, as it will be called for each underlying URL and it will keep on showing unless every `css` and `js` files are loaded

```
progressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Loading...", "Please wait YouTube is Loading...");
```

Comment: Still it's not dismiss its still showing the dialog

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this code

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Loading...", "Please wait YouTube is Loading...");
```

Hope it helps