# load html in webview with progressbar

Tags: java, html, android-studio, webview, progress-bar

I have made recylerview and when clicked in different list i want to load `html` and also add `progressbar`. I have made the layout with `webview` and `progressbar` and also followed as of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331094/add-a-progress-bar-in-webview) and many other.

this is the activity where recyclerView is shown and i want to load different html when clicked in different row of lists of recyclerView:

```java
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_abhyas);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_list);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

// i want to load different html when clicked these different list; and i have trackced these position in onNoteClick below:
        ArrayList<Rv> rvList = new ArrayList<>();
        rvList.add(new Rv(R.mipmap.blue, "१", "जन्मभूमि"));
        rvList.add(new Rv(R.mipmap.green, "२", "सन्तुष्टि"));
        rvList.add(new Rv(R.mipmap.orange, "३", "सन्दुक रुइत"));
        rvList.add(new Rv(R.mipmap.purple, "४", "थाङ्का"));

RvAdapter adapter = new RvAdapter(rvList, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
    public void onNoteCLick(int position) {
        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);

        if (position == 0){
            // i want to load here "html"

        }
        if (position == 1) {
            //i want to load here html2
        }

    }
}
```

and this is layout "webview.xml" which i created to load html with progressbar:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:max="3"
        android:progress="100"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is your question again?

Comment: Hello  @KevinNg I mean, I have made different list using recycler view; now i want to load html when clicked in different list; in method onNoteClick i have track the position of list. now i want to load html when clicked in list and i also want to add progressbar.

Comment: show your full code with xml and java, did you use adpater?

Comment: @YogeshNikamPatil sir I have added code and xml. please check that