# how to set a progress Dialog when a browser is being launched

Tags: android

I have come up with a private browser,but I want to know how to link it to my code below when the browser is being opened.

Main Class

```
b5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){   
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent i =new Intent(FiltersActivity.this,MyBrowser.class); 
        i.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Second Class

```
public class MyBrowser extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle SavedIntstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(SavedIntstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.browser);

        Uri uri = getIntent().getData(); // get Intent and the linked data
        WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView_01); // get the
                                                                // webview
                                                                // item
        webview.setWebViewClient(new Callback()); // set the object to the view
                                                // to webview
        webview.loadUrl(uri.toString()); // load the url

    }

    private class Callback extends WebViewClient { // crate a virtual class
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) { // /load
                                                                        // the
                                                                        // necessary
            return (false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: see link: http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=1331

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [`this`](http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/08/04/adding-progress-bar-on-webview-android-tutorials/) blog with complete example that shows progess of the webview in the Title Bar.

Also you can have a look in the Android Docs [`activity.setProgress(progress)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

And finally but not the least [`StackOverflow Answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537454/android-webview-progress-bar)