# WebView 2.2 vs 3.1

Tags: android, webview

Is there any different behaviors about the WebView class on Android 2.2 and 3.1 ?

Here you go some informations I got testing the same app on two different devices, the first one with Android 2.2 and the another one 3.1

- The app's target is 2.1
- The page that I want to access is an ASP.net page

Running on 2.2

- shouldOverrideUrlLoading is called normally
- onPageStarted and onPageFinished are called more than once
- onNewPicture from webview is called once, when the page ends the loading

Running on 3.1

- shouldOverrideUrlLoading isn't called, only webView.load(url) is enough to do the same work
- onPageStarted and onPageFinished are called once
- onNewPicture from webview isnt called

My problem is. I need to show a dialog while the page is loading, and I don't know how to do that with these differences.

If I create the dialog on onPageStarted and close it on onPageFinished it will show and close more than once on 2.2, but on 3.1 it will works fine

Otherwise, if I create the dialog on shouldOverrideUrlLoading and close it on onNewPicture it will works fine on 2.2 but on 3.1 it won't even appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following:

[Android WebView progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537454/android-webview-progress-bar)

to put a progress bar on a webview while it was loading, your could implement the same, bringing up a view when the percentage loaded is less than 100% and taking it down when it is 100%.  I implemented this for an Android >= 3.0 type device though.

Comment: I can't use WebChromeClient because I need to show the page and the user won't be able to navigate trhough other links. WebChromeClient give you a bar on the top of the screen that the user can change the link. Using the default WebViewClient I have the different behaviours that I mentioned above.

Comment: Not true, I have standard WebView objects running in my app, and there is NO link bar at the top!!! I have implemented my own progress metering.  Now the caviat is that my app is in 3.0 and above!

Comment: The point is: I need to set WebChromeClient and WebViewClient to have a similar aproach that I want. I was trying to use one or another, not both. So, I did a progressbar using the activity.setprogress on the onProgressChange of WebChromeClient. My real attempt was to show a dialog with a progressbar inside, but I can use this approach otherwise. Thanks a bunch !