# Set a progress bar in full screen webview Android

Tags: android, webview, progress-bar, progress

i tried to use this solutions 
[Android WebView progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537454/android-webview-progress-bar)

which gives me

```
    final ProgressBar Pbar;
    Pbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pB1);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_browser);
    browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.layout_browser);

    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    browser.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

    browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) 
           {
           if(progress < 100 && Pbar.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE){
               Pbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
           }
           Pbar.setProgress(progress);
           if(progress == 100) {
               Pbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
           }
        }
    });

    browser.loadUrl("google.com");
```

and adding a progress bar in my webview layout but it crashes, why ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
> 
<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/pB1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:padding="2dip">
</ProgressBar>
<WebView android:id="@+id/layout_browser" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
/>   
</RelativeLayout>
```

Note : i will hide my status bar that's why I tried to use this method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line `Pbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pB1);` should be  after `setContentView(R.layout.layout_browser);`

Something like,

```
setContentView(R.layout.layout_browser);
Pbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pB1);
```

Comment: ok thanks it works now but I can't see the progress bar in the emulator

Comment: Because your `ProgressBar` is hide behind `WebView`. Change the code in layout Xml file first `WebView` then `ProgressBar`.

Comment: it crashes if I put webview first, any idea ?

Comment: ok it works now, i muste change it in my code too but the progress bar appears on the middle of the screen how can i put it up ?

Comment: In your progressbar change line `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` with  `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`