# webview.load (waiting progress bar)

Tags: android

I need use a progress bar from when user click on "play" until audio is exact playing. Now there's a pause (1/2 seconds) from play button and hear audio. How check when audio is exact playing?

```
   webView1 = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);     
                webView1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webView1.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
                webView1.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
                webView1.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
                webView1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webView1.loadUrl("http://link.swf");
```

Comment: What does that code have to do with playing audio?

Comment: I using this code to hear music from a swf audio file. Thanks

Comment: Check out these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537454/android-webview-progress-bar

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149216/how-to-listen-for-a-webview-finishing-loading-a-url-in-android