# Activity Circle while WebView loads any page?

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an WebView app that uses multiple pages, I want to have a Activity Circle that shows that a new page is loading. As of right now when I click a link/button in the app it stays on the same page until the next one is fully loaded, this leaving users confused when they have bad connection.

I have Googled and looked here on Stack Overflow but only found questions asking how to set a loading indicator upon first launch.

I'm guessing I don't need to provide my code here.

Comment: By `Activity Circle`, do you mean an **indeterminate ProgressBar**?

Comment: If you mean the one that just spins until the page is finished yes, not the one that uses percent. @DerGolem

Comment: `The one that uses percent` is a **determinate** ProgressBar (usually `Linear` or `non-standard, circular`).

Comment: I want the on that is indeterminate. As I understand Progress bars shows how far it has come, while activity indicators show that something is loading or being sent etc.

Comment: For **HTML pages** (you are using a `WebView`), an **animated GIF** is more than enough.

Comment: Yeah but how do I say that when the user clicks a link, hide the webview and show the activity circle until the new page is fully loaded?

Comment: You can do it **without** hiding the WebView (and stressing the user with such an **UI inconsistency**) Just as you'd do in a `dynamic HTML web page`. Clear the contents, show the GIF until the newe content is loaded.

Comment: So t's better do enable this on the HTML side and not the Android side?

Comment: Once you start building an HTML application... go on this way. It's useless to mix Android and HTML. I normally use WebViews only to show the User Guide (to provide something too hard for a TextView, such expanding/collapsing help branches).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android WebView progress bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537454/android-webview-progress-bar)

Comment: http://itpeoplealwayswelcome.blogspot.in/2014/11/android-progressdialog-display-before.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand your question, you want to show the `progress bar` if the page is loading in the `webview` and when page is fully loaded then display the content of the page. Right ?

Here is what you can do.

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

final Activity activity = this;
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
     // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
     // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%

     // Here you can check if the progress is = 100 or not
     if(progress == 100){
     // hide the progress bar
     // show the webview
     } else {
     // show the progress bar
     // hide the webview
     }

   }
});
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String           failingUrl) {
   Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
 });

 webview.loadUrl("http://developer.android.com/");
```

Code reference from [Webviews - Android developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Comment: You understood my request perfectly, reading the code I feel like it should work perfectly. Going to try it when I get home