# Android Webview Progress bar when loading

Tags: android

I want progress bar when website loading in the webview.

I searched for solution not satisfied.

Please anyone help me?

When I click any link in webpage it loads perfectly but I want to know how much it loaded. So, I need progress bar in top of webview while loading

Comment: Specify  what are you looking for... Mayby post image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a progress view, and when the webview is loading (using `onProgressChanged`), set the current progress, and when finished, hide it.

It is so easy and there are solutions over there for that.

Edit: IMO this is a duplicate of [Android WebView progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537454/android-webview-progress-bar)

Comment: You're welcome. Next time use **Google** to find a solution please ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is example code how you can use webview client for this i have used gif imageview you can use progressbar instead it.

```
public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        ivGif.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anim_set_frames);
        AnimationDrawable progressAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) ivGif.getBackground();
        progressAnimation.start();
        ivGif.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        ivGif.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}




    webViewBooking.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    webViewBooking.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webViewBooking.loadUrl(payment_url);
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple way is like this;

```
     public class MyActivity extends Activity {
     private static final int PROGRESS = 0x1;

     private ProgressBar mProgress;
     private int mProgressStatus = 0;

     private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

     protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
         super.onCreate(icicle);

         setContentView(R.layout.progressbar_activity);

         mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

         // Start lengthy operation in a background thread
         new Thread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 while (mProgressStatus < 100) {
                     mProgressStatus = doWork();

                     // Update the progress bar
                     mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                         public void run() {
                             mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                         }
                     });
                 }
             }
         }).start();
     }
 }
```

Comment: You don't need a second thread for this, just use `onProgressChanged`

Comment: Thanks for your answer