# How to apply pull to refresh feature like chrome in web-view android studio?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, pull-to-refresh

I am trying to set up a pull to refresh feature like chrome (swipe refresh layout). The loading bar disappears after pull.
How can i fix this?

I've tried various code samples from stack overflow... but none of them seem to work.
Swipe to refresh works but disappears right after pull.

Swipe refresh in main activity java

```
mySwipeRefreshLayout = this.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);

        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        browser.reload();
                        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                }
        );
```

I Just want the loading icon to load till the full page is refreshed like chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to keep the loading till the page loaded you don't have to use                         `mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false)` inside your refresh listener , because your are disabling  it just after the refresh start.

instead you have to use it when your loading is done . let say as example you have a `webview` , so you should listen on the `webview` progress like this example :

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
          mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey, also is there a way to add a progress bar while loading... Just like chrome?

Comment: Hi @ADITYAG if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. for the progressbar check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537454/android-webview-progress-bar